# OpenStreetMap data editor for postgis database data/osm2pgsql result

Tags: database, openstreetmap

Is there an editor for OSM data which allows direct read and write to a PostGIS database taking advantage of its features for performance?

**Background**: I've been checking on OSM data editor and found `josm` (7758) and `merkaator` ( 0.18.1) which seem great but have trouble with large input files. Problem for `josm` (still) is that the UI is blocking (the parallel reading of the input is very efficient though and should be adapted by a lot of other OSM data editors) and it'll take some time (of development) until every operation is non-blocking or abortable, i.e. smooth. `merkaator` takes for ever to parse a relatively small set of data and I consider it not usable (see test data details below).

Although very smart improvements to parallel parsing have been made (in `josm`), the problem of parsing XML is devoted to the decision of stream of memory based handling of the input and *any* editor based on parsing files will never reach an appropriate performance allowing to navigate in OSM planet snapshot at will without performance impacts. Using databases (with smart caches) as a backend of an editor would fix a lot of issues by taking advantage of partitioning, hashing, indices, etc. (all the reasons why we actually use databases...).

I tested the latest snapshot of Berlin which has a relatively high coverage and therefore large volume of data (currently ~750 MB), but at the end an application should be able to handle an arbitrary large input without blocking UI.